# How to add data to the listbox by clicking Save Button :

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i add the data to listbox1 by pressing the Save button.I have done the code of listbox1 but not of the button.Below is the code

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 
  {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
         public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

         }

         private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
             listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
             listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text);
             listBox1.Items.Add(textBox4.Text);
         }
     } 
  }
```

Comment: "What have you tried?". I don't even understand what you are asking for... When the button is clicked, do your changes to listBox1

Comment: i want to add the text entered in textbox to the listbox by clicking the button.

Comment: you should move the code from the SelectedIndexChanged event handler of the listbox to the Click event handler of the button.

Comment: How to do it.I am the beginner .i have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want on button click the same thing to happen as on SelectedIndexChanged(), you just copy the code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox4.Text);
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox4.Text);*/
}
```

If this is not it, you have to give more information about what should happen.

Comment: It Works..Thanks. Now i have addeed the clear button to clear the listbox.what will be the code for clear button ?

Answer (score 3):

Delete the `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event and put the content to the `button1_Click` event.

It should look like this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
         listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
         listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text);
         listBox1.Items.Add(textBox4.Text);
      }

  } 
}
```

And don't forget to remove the `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event from the ListBox in the **UI** editor too.